# using hidden fields in express js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, ejs

Im trying to pass value of a hidden id field and use it to retriev records from mongodb and display it on profile page,after clicking  "read more" on index page.This the index.ejs:

```
     <% for(i=0; i<users.length; i++){%>
        <div class="col-lg-3 center">
            <div class="text-center">
                <img class="img img-circle" src="<%= users[i].image %>" height="120px" width="120px" alt=""> <br>
                <h4><b><%= users[i].fname %> <%= users[i].lname %></b></h4>
                <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                <li><a href="<%= users[i].linkedin %>"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="<%= users[i].gitHub %>"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= users[i]._id %>" >
                <p><%=users[i].bio %>....<a href="prof">Read More</a></p>

            </div>
        </div><!-- col-lg-3 -->
        <% } %>
```

and here is  profile.ejs:

```
 <div class="medium-4 small-12 columns">
    <h3> <%= users.fname %>  <%= users.lname %></h3>
    <p>Username: <%= users.username %></p>
    <p>Email: <%= users.email %></p>
    <p> Software Developer at <%= users.role %></p>
  </div>
```

and express routes ,users.js.

```
  app.get('/prof',function(req, res) {
     var id=req.body.id;
     var user = new User();
    mongoose.model('User').findById(id,function(err, users){
       console.log(users);
        res.render('pages/profile',{users:users});
     });
  });
```

This gives me an error "Cannot read property 'username' of null.."

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you try `users[i].bio.username` instead? If I'm not wrong `users[i].bio` is null.

Comment: "Cannot read property 'username' of null.." tells us mongod is not returning results. try to console the hidden posted value what are the results.

Comment: index page is working ,users[i].bio is not null. Only when i click "Read more"   i get the err "Cannot read property 'username' of null.."

Comment: it return undefine @owaishanif786

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a `GET` operation yet you are trying to send the `id` value through the `POST` parameters which are grabbed using `req.body.variable_name`.

In this case you don't need a hidden field as that needs a `POST` operation to send to the server. Try sending the `id` as a URL parameter which can be grabbed using `req.param.id` or `req.query.id`, for example

```
http://example.com/api/users?id=4&token=sdfa3&geo=us
```

or

```
http://example.com/api/users/4/sdfa3/us
```

---

If you want to get a query parameter `?id=57ada56845b8466147fc35b0`, then use `req.query`

**URL:**

```
// GET /prof?id=57ada56845b8466147fc35b0
```

**Markup:**

```
<p><%=users[i].bio %>....<a href="prof?id=<%= users[i]._id %>">Read More</a></p>
```

**Route:**

```
app.get('/prof', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.query.id; // 57ada56845b8466147fc35b0
    mongoose.model('User').findById(id, function(err, user){
        console.log(user);
        res.render('pages/profile', { users: user });
    });
});
```

---

For the other parameter usage

**URL:**

```
// GET /prof/57ada56845b8466147fc35b0
```

use `req.params.id`

**Markup:**

```
<p><%=users[i].bio %>....<a href="prof/<%= users[i]._id %>">Read More</a></p>
```

**Route:**

```
app.get('/prof/:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id; //57ada56845b8466147fc35b0
    mongoose.model('User').findById(id, function(err, user){
        console.log(user);
        res.render('pages/profile', { users: user });
    });
});
```